# How would you go about activating numerous left clicks?

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to create a script (actually a Bookmarklet) for a game I play. So, when I activate the bookmarklet it constantly spam clicks with a delay of 1 second and last for 10minutes..

This is what I have so far:

```
function click() { // code } setInterval(function(){ setInterval(function(){click();},1); }, 1); click();
```

Comment: I'm going to have to disappoint you that this is not how Javascript works.

Comment: I though it was possible

Answer (score 2):

Not gonna lie, you didn't give much information. When asking a SO question it's best to be as specific and precise as possible. This will probably take several exchanges, but I'll do my best to help. Ask any questions you have about this snippet.

```js
var elementToClick = document.querySelector('#idofbuttontoclick'); // some sort of selector
window.setInterval(function() {
  elementToClick.click();
}, 1000);
```